# Python / Pandas: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 133: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas, unidecoder

I'm trying to build a method to import multiple types of csvs or Excels and standardize it. Everything was running smoothly until a certain csv showed up, that brought me this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 133: invalid continuation byte
```

I'm building a set of try/excepts to include variations of data types but for this one I couldn't figure out how to prevent.

```
    if csv_or_excel_path[-3:]=='csv':
        try: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path)
        except:
            try: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,sep=';')
            except:
                try:table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,sep='\t')
                except:
                    try: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,encoding='utf-8')
                    except:
                        try: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,encoding='utf-8',sep=';')
                        except: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,encoding='utf-8',sep='\t')
```

By the way, the separator of the file is ";".

So:

a) I understand it would be easier to track down the problem if I could identify what's the character in "position 133", however I'm not sure how to find that out. Any suggestions?

b) Does anyone have a suggestion on what to include in that try/except sequence to skip this prob?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the CSV?

Comment: @FHTMitchell actually I'm trying to copy/paste it but when I try to do it blanks out the text box

Comment: Header will be relevant as I think it means the 133rd character in the file. It's probably one of the characters in "informação". You'll need to convert the file to UTF format first before loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, this is probably better than multiple `try/except`s

```
def read_csv(filepath):
     if os.path.splitext(filepath)[1] != '.csv':
          return  # or whatever
     seps = [',', ';', '\t']                    # ',' is default
     encodings = [None, 'utf-8', 'ISO-8859-1']  # None is default
     for sep in seps:
         for encoding in encodings:
              try:
                  return pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding=encoding, sep=sep)
              except Exception:  # should really be more specific 
                  pass
     raise ValueError("{!r} is has no encoding in {} or seperator in {}"
                      .format(filepath, encodings, seps))
```

Comment: I found that sometimes also `utf-16` is used, maybe it worth to add to the list

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to do

```
with open(path_to_file, encoding="utf8", errors="ignore") as f:
    table = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";")
```

By default, `errors="ignore"` will omit problematic byte sequences from `read()` calls. You can also supply a fill value for such byte sequences. But in general this should reduce the need for lots of painful error handling and nested try-excepts.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the support @woblers and @FHTMitchell. The problem was a weird enconding the CSV had: ISO-8859-1.

I fixed it by adding a few lines to the try/except sequence. Here you can see the full version of it.

```
    if csv_or_excel_path[-3:]=='csv':
        try: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path)
        except:
            try: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,sep=';')
            except:
                try:table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,sep='\t')
                except:
                    try: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,encoding='utf-8')
                    except:
                        try: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,encoding='utf-8',sep=';')
                        except:
                            try: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,encoding='utf-8',sep='\t')
                            except:
                                try:table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,encoding = "ISO-8859-1", sep=";")
                                except:
                                    try: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,encoding = "ISO-8859-1", sep=";")
                                    except: table=pd.read_csv(csv_or_excel_path,encoding = "ISO-8859-1", sep="\t")
```